# how to find elements in xml data?

Tags: xml

When we have a nested elements in XML function, how we could get the access to them?
I use :

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
       print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It could be helpful to add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: @Casey: how I can do so? could you please more clear?